# bash command for with if statement

Tags: bash

I am trying to write a bash code which run over a folder where few .json files are allocated, and depending which ones is i want to run a specific Tippecanoe command with specific parameters.

```
for i in $$(find ./ -type f -name '*.json'); do
        if [$i.json == 'file1.json'] && [$i_part2.json == 'file1_part2.json']
            then 
                tippecanoe --minimum-zoom=13 --maximum-zoom=16 --read-parallel -b13 -r13 -pc -l $i -o "$i.mbtiles" "$i" "$i_cetroid.json" 
                echo $i done
        else
        if $(echo $i).json == 'file2.json' or $(echo $i)_cetroid.json == 'file2_part2.json' 
        then tippecanoe --minimum-zoom=13 --maximum-zoom=16 --read-parallel -b13 -r13 -pc -l $i-o "$i.mbtiles" "$i" "$i_cetroid.json" 
            echo $i done
        else
        if $(echo $i).json == 'file3.json' or $(echo $i)_cetroid.json == 'file3_part2.json' 
        then tippecanoe --minimum-zoom=5 --maximum-zoom=16 --read-parallel -b5 -r5 -pc -l $i-o "$i.mbtiles" "$i" "$i_centroid.json" 
            echo $i done
        else
break
        fi
done
```

I have gone through it but I am getting different errors if I split the code individually

Comment: Spacing matters.  `[` is a command, but `[file.json` is (probably) not.

Answer (score 1):

You really shouldn't parse the output of `find` like this, but you might be looking for:

```
for i in $(find . -name '*.json'); do
    if [ "$i" = file1 ]; then 
        tippecanoe --minimum-zoom=13 --maximum-zoom=16 --read-parallel -b13 -r13 -pc -l $i -o "$i.mbtiles" "$i" "$i_part2.json" 
        echo ${i}done
    elif test "$i" = file3; then
        tippecanoe --minimum-zoom=5 --maximum-zoom=16 --read-parallel -b5 -r5 -pc -l $i -o "$i.mbtiles" "$i" "$i_centroid.json" 
        echo ${i}done
    else
        break
    fi
done
```

(I've omitted the file2 portion, since your original code seems to rely on the string `cetroid` being equal to the string `part2`, which is logically impossible.).  Also note that I used `test` instead of `[` on the second case.  There's absolutely no difference between `test` and `[` (30 years ago, it was common to find that one was a shell builtin and the other was not, but that's rare now) other than the fact that `[` requires that its final argument be `]` and that it confuses many people.  Because of the unnecessary confusion, I tend to prefer `test` and recommend it.   Note that this could (and should!) be refactored to reduce redundancy:

```
for i in $(find . -name '*.json'); do
    if [ "$i" = file1 ]; then 
        minzoom=13
        b=13
        suffix=part
    elif [ "$i" = file3 ]; then
        minzoom=5
        b=5
        suffix=centroid
    else
        break
    fi
    tippecanoe --minimum-zoom=$minzoom --maximum-zoom=16 --read-parallel -b$b -r$b -pc -l $i -o "$i.mbtiles" "$i" "${i}_${suffix}.json" 
    echo ${i}done
done
```

Which could be further simplified with a case statement:

```
for i in $(find . -name '*.json'); do
    case "$i" in
    file1)
        minzoom=13
        b=13
        suffix=part
    ;;
    file3)
        minzoom=5
        b=5
        suffix=centroid
    ;;
    *) break;;
    esac
    tippecanoe --minimum-zoom=$minzoom --maximum-zoom=16 --read-parallel -b$b -r$b -pc -l $i -o "$i.mbtiles" "$i" "${i}_${suffix}.json" 
    echo ${i}done
done
```

Comment: Im getting the same errors:  syntax error near unexpected token `'$'do\r` and `for i in $(find ./*.json);do` similar to what i got when adding the if statements

Comment: Note: `find ./*.json` is *not* the way you want to invoke find.  (Unless you have directories named `*.json` that you want to search.)